# Is it possible Laravel create() method to insert double time same values?

Tags: php, laravel

there is a very strange situation with one of my Laravel scripts. I have a crawler script, which takes values from other website and saves them into my database. In order to check easily that i have already that value, I save the primary key of the other website into my database. Before every insert (Laravel create() method) I am check if that key exists in my table and if it does not exist, than I can insert the value. That is pretty straight forward. Unfortunately sometimes (I cannot find any repetitive case) i have double values for a same primary key of the other website.

I have a laravel-debugbar installed and when i check all database queries, there is no double insert query, which is pretty strange.
I have made outputs to check if some of my loops is causing that problem, but not.

Here is some of my code, if anybody has other clue, why is that happening:

```
$check = FootballGame::where('foreign_id', '=', $key)->get();
// echo $key." ".count($check)."<br>\n";

if(count($check) == 0) {
    if(strip_tags($objResultGame[5][0]) != 'CAN.' && strip_tags($objResultGame[5][0]) != 'POSTP.') {
        $stats = $this->get_game_stats($this->domain.$objResultGame[1][0], $sport_id);
        if(!empty($stats)) {
            FootballGame::create([
                'foreign_id' => $key,
                'season_id' => $season->id, 
                'stage_id' => (($stage_id > 0) ? $stage_id : null), 
                'round_type' => $gr, 
                'round' => $r, 
                'group_id' => ($group_id == 0) ? null : $group_id, 
                'datetime' => $stats['datetime'], 
                'team1_id' => $stats['team1'], 
                'team2_id' => $stats['team2'],
                'home' => $stats['home'], 
                'away' => $stats['away'], 
                'home_ht' => $stats['home_ht'], 
                'away_ht' => $stats['away_ht'], 
                'overtime' => $stats['overtime'], 
                'winner_team_id' => $stats['winner_team_id'], 
                'comment' => $stats['comment'], 
                'status' => 1
            ]);
            echo "Add match: ".$group_id." ".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."<br>\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Database schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `games_football` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `foreign_id` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `season_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `stage_id` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `group_id` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `round_type` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `round` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `team1_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `team2_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `home` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `away` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `home_ht` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `away_ht` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `overtime` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `winner_team_id` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `comment` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `status` smallint(6) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `games_football`
--
ALTER TABLE `games_football`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `games_football_foreign_id_unique` (`foreign_id`),
  ADD KEY `games_football_season_id_index` (`season_id`),
  ADD KEY `games_football_stage_id_index` (`stage_id`),
  ADD KEY `games_football_group_id_index` (`group_id`),
  ADD KEY `games_football_team1_id_index` (`team1_id`),
  ADD KEY `games_football_team2_id_index` (`team2_id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `games_football`
--
ALTER TABLE `games_football`
  MODIFY `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;COMMIT;
```

Comment: The primary key must be unique and DBMS cannot allow creating different rows with same primary keys

Comment: @Nikita i have my own primary key. For my database it is a foreign key, because it comes from other website. Anyway, i have tried also to make that field unique, but Laravel gives an error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry and that killes the script :(

Comment: It is right and expected behavior for duplicate entry.

Comment: That's why i am checking first if there is entry with that key and if not it comes to the create() method. But how is it possible to not exist such entry and couple of lines after that to say that there is duplicate entry ?

Comment: Are you sure that foreign_id is a troubling column? Can you paste to Pastebin or another service your table schema?

Comment: Yes, that is the field causing the duplicate entry error: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '4n0DE382' for key 'games_football_foreign_id_unique'

Comment: It is a string) It is case sensitive string? Do you trim() spaces?

Comment: `DEFAULT NULL` bad decision for unique column

Comment: Can you try `ILIKE` instead `=` in where clause? It is only for debugging

Comment: @Nikita it seems that ILIKE is not supported on my mysql server :(

Comment: Ok, I am sorry this query from PostgreSQL. `LIKE` is suitable for MySQL. `ILIKE` it is case insensitive like. In your case `LIKE` will be good. But you also can use `LOWER()` function (in raw query) or `strtolower()` PHP function

Comment: And add `!$key` condition)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with !$key, but only that: $check = FootballGame::where('foreign_id', 'LIKE', strtolower($key))->get(); doesnt work again. The very strange thing is that in the queries output i do not see insert two times for the same $key ...

Comment: key should not be null. 
Can you select * from games_football where foreign_id = null?

Comment: I have one more version) maybe foreign_id from another site is longer than 20 symbols in needed collation and your table contains only part of foreign_id

Comment: unfortunately that is not the problem. the key is max 10 chars :( it is much complicated error

Comment: I'm sorry but I can not reproduce the error. You should Log every variable of this error state. Why you can't find an existed row in DB? I would be very happy if you inform me when you resolve this problem)

Comment: @Nikita thanks for the help. I hope i will find the error. Still struggling with that. Strangely the error comes only on the webserver. On my local machine i dont an error

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need a more restrict check

```
$game = FootballGame::where('foreign_id', '=', $key)->first();

if(!$game->exists) {

     //other code here

}
```

Comment: isn't it the same ?

Comment: Would you try plz

Comment: No, it does not work. if(!$game->exists), does not work, but i have changed it to if(!$game), but also the same thing as before :(

Comment: why ` if(!$game->exists)` did not work ? Any error ?

Comment: yes, the error is: Trying to get property of non-object